Metadata filter with Elasticsearch and MultiQueryRetriever (Langchain)
I'm trying to use MultiQueryRetriever to do a research in Elasticsearch providing metadata in order to filter results.
from langchain.retrievers.multi_query import MultiQueryRetriever

async def generative_search(query: str, request_results: dict, summaries: bool, is_keyword_search: bool = False):

    es_retriever = CustomElasticSearchRetriever()
    num_token_multiretriever_template = num_tokens_from_string(f'{MULTIRETRIEVER_TEMPLATE} {query}')
    
    retriever_prompt = create_prompt(MULTIRETRIEVER_TEMPLATE, ["question"])
    
    multi_retriever = MultiQueryRetriever.from_llm(
        retriever=es_retriever,
        llm = openai_model(num_token_multiretriever_template),
        prompt=retriever_prompt,
    )
    
    unique_docs = multi_retriever.get_relevant_documents(query=query, metadata=request_results})

where CustomElasticSearchRetriever is the following class:
class CustomElasticSearchRetriever(BaseRetriever, BaseModel):
    def get_relevant_documents(self, query: str, metadata: dict = None) ->list[Document]:
        metadata = metadata or {}
        logging.info(f"Query: {query}, Metadata: {metadata}")
        return search_backend(query=query, metadata=metadata)
    
    async def aget_relevant_documents(self, query: str) -> list:
        NotImplementedError

The log in "get_relevant_documents" prints that metadata is always empty, even if I know for sure that request_results has some values.
I tried to use the "metadata" parameter in MultiQueryRetriever but it does not work.
I tried to pass parameters to get_relevant_documents as dict:
unique_docs = multi_retriever.get_relevant_documents(query=query, metadata=request_results})

but I got the same empty metadata from the log.
There is a way to pass metadata through MultiQueryRetriever in order to use Elasticsearch filter on documents?
